# vuex mutation doesn't update DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuex

I'm rendering a list based on an object. I'm adding new elements to this object by help of the mutations. When I log this.$store.state.myObject to console, I can see that it is updating. However, my list is not updated.

Actually, **I got lucky and I fixed this issue** by adding the line of code below in my mutation. (I found out that this can help DOM update.)

But I'd like to learn if this is a good solution.

```
state.realms = Object.assign({}, state.realms)
```

Here is my whole mutation:

```
addToRealms: (state, val) => {
        var id = val.id
        var realmName = val.name.en_US
        state.realms[id] = { name: realmName }
        state.realms = Object.assign({}, state.realms)
        }
```

And here is my vue page code

```
<q-btn flat
  v-for="(realm,code) in realms"
  :key="code"
  @click="selectRealm(realm)"
  :label="realm.name"
  clickable/>
```

I defined realms as a computed property.

```
computed: {
realms () {
  return this.$store.state.realms
}
```

Further info:
I use vue.js devtools extension, when I track my commit on vuex store I can see that I'm really changing the state. But It doesnt affect immediately. If I press commit all button, my list gets updated.

[image: Commit All Button on Vue Devtools]
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
state.realms = Object.assign({}, state.realms)
```

you basically are recreating a new object based on the previous one (breaking the references in case there are not nested objects), and that's the reason why in this way the list get updated.

Give a read [to this article](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/copying-objects-in-javascript) to understand more about deep-cloning and breaking references.

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object

When you add new properties to the object, those are not reactive. To make them reactive, use the Vue.set() method, ([docs here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)).

```
Vue.set(state.realms[id],'name', realmName);
```

Comment: I tried this in my mutation, I logged state.realms right after Vue.set(), and I can see its updated. But, it doesn't update my rendered list (dom). I feel like I need to fire an event which updates the DOM object which related with my Vue store state.

Comment: Yeah, I see. 
Try with: 

state.obj = { ...state.realms.id, name: realmName }